# Visual Studio 2015 Background Application GrovePi.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi3, grovepi+

```
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using GrovePi.Sensors;
using GrovePi.Common;
using GrovePi.I2CDevices;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using Windows.Devices;
using GrovePi;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CompassXYZ
{
    public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            Pin Compass = Pin.DigitalPin3;
            string CompassX = Compass.ToString();
            string CompassY = Compass.ToString();
            string CompassZ = Compass.ToString();
            while (true)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"X = {CompassX.GetHashCode()}, Y = {CompassY.GetHashCode()}, Z = {CompassZ.GetHashCode()}");

            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Hi Guys!

I'm a student trying to display 3 values from my Compass sensor on my GrovePi connected to my raspberry pi 3 running on Visual Studio 2015 Background Application, I need some pointers on how to display it correctly, so I really hope you guys could help me. Thanks!